# SQL - Rectify my Query please

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit : Context is I am making a report using reportviewer. It is an invoice the first SELECT does it perfect (i.e. customer name & delivery details). The second SELECT is used to get arrears till beginning of this month. Alternate way (read 'Query') to do it are welcome.
P.S. (if anyone has already done similar work, your query shall be helpful )

Thanks, 
Desperate Now

: Edit Closed

```
SELECT delvoucher.dvdate, 
           delvoucher.dvno, 
           delvoucher.vehicleno, 
           delvoucher.salesman, 
           dvdetails.[desc], 
           dvdetails.supply, 
           dvdetails.empty, 
           dvdetails.amount, 
           dvdetails.rate, 
           delvoucher.title, 
           customer.currentaddress, 
           customer.phone, 
           customer.code
    FROM   delvoucher 
    INNER JOIN dvdetails ON delvoucher.id = dvdetails.pid 
    INNER JOIN customer ON delvoucher.title = customer.title
    WHERE YEAR(delvoucher.dvdate) = YEAR(@i) AND MONTH(delvoucher.dvdate) = MONTH(@i)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT SUM(amount) - sum(recvd)
     FROM dvdetails 
     INNER JOIN delvoucher ON delvoucher.id = dvdetails.pid
     WHERE delvoucher.dvdate < DATEADD(month, 1, @i))
```

If I remove UNION part it runs ok. The union part gives me arrears till previous month for the specific client. Any other way to get arrear balance of the client

Comment: The query is for Master-child Invoive  report of reportviewer and has SQL Server at backend

Comment: Have a look at how you should use [UNION](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx). "The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all queries." and "The data types must be compatible."

Comment: its the same table :)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: the union I am applying is on same table so the number of columns and structure is same too :)

Comment: Yeah, but you need the same number and type of column in the SELECT statment.

Comment: It does not matter what tables you are using what matters is the columns you specify in the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix(but i dont think this is what you would like to get):

```
SELECT 
       0 as SUMPLACEHOLDER,
       delvoucher.dvdate, 
       delvoucher.dvno, 
       delvoucher.vehicleno, 
       delvoucher.salesman, 
       dvdetails.[desc], 
       dvdetails.supply, 
       dvdetails.empty, 
       dvdetails.amount, 
       dvdetails.rate, 
       delvoucher.title, 
       customer.currentaddress, 
       customer.phone, 
       customer.code
FROM   delvoucher 
INNER JOIN dvdetails ON delvoucher.id = dvdetails.pid 
INNER JOIN customer ON delvoucher.title = customer.title
WHERE YEAR(delvoucher.dvdate) = YEAR(@i) AND MONTH(delvoucher.dvdate) = MONTH(@i)
UNION ALL
(SELECT SUM(amount) - sum(recvd), null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null
 FROM dvdetails 
 INNER JOIN delvoucher ON delvoucher.id = dvdetails.pid
 WHERE delvoucher.dvdate < DATEADD(month, 1, @i))
```

Comment: Thanks but Is there a way I can have sum(amount)- sum(recvd) in first SELECT query (no need of union)

Answer (score 0):

The first mandatory condition to use Union is, your select queries must have same number of columns and the format of columns must be same. In your case, the second select query is having only 1 column which will definitely not work. You can either run the queries separately or change the second query to have same number of columns and format.